# Update de multiplas Imagens

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Meu código atualmente esta fazendo o seu papel bem upando e colocando a marca d'água nas imagens do upload, porem gostaria de estar armazenando os nomes de todas as imagens no banco.

```
$idnoticia = $_GET['idnoticia'];

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$watermark_x = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_y = imagesy($watermark);
$dir = "../img/$idnoticia/";

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $index => $file) {
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
   imagecopy($image, $watermark, round(imagesx($image) / 1) - round($watermark_x / 1),    round(imagesy($image) / 1) - round($watermark_y / 1), 0, 0, $watermark_x,    $watermark_y);
   imagejpeg($image, $dir . preg_replace('/.jpeg|.jpg/i', '', $_FILES['files']['name'][$index]) . '_wm.jpg');
   imagedestroy($image);
}

imagedestroy($watermark);
echo "Envio Completado!";

$sqlInsert = 'UPDATE noticias SET galeria = "$image" WHERE idnoticia = "$idnoticia';
$stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert2);
$stmt->bindParam("galeria", $image);
$stmt->execute();
```

Gostaria de armazenar os nomes das imagens no campo `galeria` como (img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg), colocando um delimitador para quando for exibir facilitar.

É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro armazene os nomes em um array enquanto roda o seu foreach:

```
$nomes = array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $index => $file) {
    (...)
    $nomes[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$index]) . '_wm.jpg';
}
```

Na hora de salvar, concatene usando a função implode, no exemplo tendo como separador uma vírgula e um espaço:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php

```
$sqlInsert = 'UPDATE noticias SET galeria = "'.implode(', ', $nomes).'"  WHERE idnoticia = "$idnoticia';
```

Espero ter ajudado.